# flask server side session object that isn't serializable

Tags: python, api, flask, scikit-learn

I've decided to create an API for an algorithm I created. The idea is the user would pass some text using a POST using json, and I would run the text through the algorithm and pass it back.

The problem I'm running into is that in order to run the algorithm, I need to create an sklearn feature_extraction CountVectorizer object. The creation of this object has some overhead, so I'd rather just create one at the start of the session, then allow users to execute requests on their session's CountVectorizer for the remainder of the session.

The CountVectorizer is not serializable, so I can't put it on the session dictionary. Any ideas on how I would create this object at the start of a users session and have it go away when the session expires?

Comment: How do you handle user session? In flask, `g` object can be used as a 'global' object per request. That means you can put anything to `g` at the begin of a request then use them until the the request ends.

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the concept of a request and session. Can a request be thought of as a single HTTP request of POST or GET to my application? If so, I would lose the data stored on the g object when they call a new end-point. I want to re-use the data that they pass to my first end-point called "/set_data" on many requests after it to another end-point called "/calculate".